# C: strtok returns first value and then NULL

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am simply trying to return every word in a string, but strtok returns the first word and then immediately null thereafter:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Get the interesting file contents
    char *filestr = get_file(argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", filestr);

    char *word;

    word =  strtok(filestr, ";\"'-?:{[}](), \n");

    while (word != NULL) {
        word = strtok(NULL, ";\"'-?:{[}](), \n");
        printf("This was called.  %s\n", word);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

get_file simply opens the specified path and returns the file's contents as a string.  The `printf("%s\n", filestr);` command shown above successfully prints out the entirety of any given file.  Hence, I do not think get_file() is the problem.

If I call strtok on `char test[] = "this is a test string"` instead of filestr, then it correctly returns each of the words.  If, however, I make the contents of the file gotten by get_file() to be "this is a string," then it returns "this" and then (null).

By request, here is the code for get_file():

```
// Take the path to the file as a string and return a string with all that
//  file's contents
char *get_file (char *dest) {
    // Define variables that will be used
    size_t length;
    FILE* file;
    char* data;
    file = fopen(dest, "rb");

    // Go to end of stream
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    // Set the int length to the end seek value of the stream
    length = ftell(file);
    // Go back to the beginning of the stream for when we actually read contents
    rewind(file);

    // Define the size of the char array str
    data = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * length + 1);

    // Read the stream into the string str
    fread(data, 1, length, file);

    // Close the stream
    fclose(file);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: One question - Your printf() is after the second strtok() so you can't be seeing the first word of the file printed, you must be seeing the second? The code looks right to me - are you *sure* you posted the exact code that is failing?

Comment: Thanks. Your usage of `strtok()` looks okay. One issue (maybe not related to this problem) is that `get_data()` doesn't nul terminate the string it reads. Is this just a simple text file you're giving it?

Comment: If you look at what you say, above you said that when it reads the file it prints "This" and NULL. To me that suggests your file is not plain ASCII. The first printf prints "This". The first strtork reads "This" and the second one (in the loop) then goes to the next one which if the end of string and prints NULL.

Comment: @FatalError: Yes, I am giving it a simple text file.  Hold, on, though.  At the request of peterept, I tried to make sure that the code I posted was the properly failing code, so I copied it to a new C project, and it worked as expected!  Let me comment out lines in my entire program that I thought were unrelated until I discover what voodoo is causing it to stop working within my larger program.

Comment: @peterept: Yes, that was a mistake in my copying the code over to StackOverflow.  I know that the code I have posted would not actually print the first word.  In this case, it would merely print (null).  Sorry.

Comment: I discovered the problem was because I was calling another function, get_words(), before I attempted to get all the words in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Are you passing a binary file with null characters in it?

get_file () is correctly returning a character buffer, but (for example), if I give your function a .png file the buffer looks like this

(gdb) p data[0] @32
$5 = "\211PNG\r\n\032\n\000\000\000\rIHDR\000\000\003\346\000\000\002\230\b\006\000\000\000\376?"

You can see that after the PNG\r\n, it has null characters, so you can't really treat the return value of get_file () as a string.  You'd need to treat it like a character array and return the total length manually and not rely on null termination.

Then, as its currently written, you can't rely on strtok, since it stop processing after it hits your first null characters.  You could work around this by doing a pass over your data and converting all the null characters into something else, or you could implement a version of strtok that works on buffers of a given length.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I led us off the trail, thinking that the problem was in the code I originally posted.  I submitted a post identifying the real problem, although I do not see how to fix it.

Comment: edited after seeing how get_file () was implemented.   Looks like you solved your problem though. :)